# How to update model (Variable) in custom python operator (tf.py_func)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to write a custom `Op` in `python`, which will generate an output based on a model and another op that will update the model. In the following sample code, I have a very simple model of just a scaler, `w` (but in reality it will be a nxm matrix). I figured out how to "read" the model as demonstrated in the `custom_model_read_op` function (in reality much more complicated). However, how can I create something similar that will update `w` in some custom complicated way (using `custom_model_update_op`)? I assume this is possible given the fact that `Optimizer` ops like SGD are able to do this. Thanks in advance!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

# Create a model
w = tf.Variable(numpy.random.randn(), name="weight")
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(), name="X")

def custom_model_read_op(i, w):
    y = i*float(w)
    return y
y = tf.py_func(custom_model_read_op, [X, w], [tf.float64], name="read_func")

def custom_model_update_op(i, w):


 ==>       # How to update w (the model stored in a Variable above) based on the value of i and some crazy logic?

    return 0
crazy_update = tf.py_func(custom_model_update_op, [X, w], [tf.int64], name="update_func")



with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(10):
        y_out, __ = sess.run([y, crazy_update], feed_dict={X: i})
        print("y=", "{:.4f}".format(y_out[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure this is the best way, but it accomplishes when I need. I don't have a `py_func` where the update on `w` occurs, but I do update it in the `read_op`, passing it back as a return value, and finally  using the `assign` function to modify it outside of the custom op. If any Tensorflow experts can confirm that this is a good legitimate way to do that, I'd appreciate it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

# Create a model
w = tf.Variable(numpy.random.randn(), name="weight")
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(), name="X")

def custom_model_read_op(i, w):
    y = i*float(w)
    w = custom_model_update(w)
    return y, w
y = tf.py_func(custom_model_read_op, [X, w], [tf.float64, tf.float64], name="read_func")

def custom_model_update(w):
    # update w (the model stored in a Variable above) based on the vaue of i and some crazy logic
    return w + 1

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(10):
        y_out, w_modified = sess.run(y, feed_dict={X: i})
        print("y=", "{:.4f}".format(y_out))
        assign_op = w.assign(w_modified)
        sess.run(assign_op)
        print("w=", "{:.4f}".format(sess.run(w)))
```

Comment: I was about to write an answer suggesting `tf.assign`, that's the right approach. You can also use `tf.control_dependencies` to force the assign to occur in the normal course of operations in the graph so you don't need to explicitly call `sess.run(assign_op)`, but both methods work